# Best way (regex?) to delete all occurrences of char in string plus next two chars after each occurrence

Tags: javascript, regex, performance

I have a string that holds certain markers, and after each marker is certain value (unknown beforehand), composed of two or one chars. I want to remove both the markers and next two chars.

For example, string is:

```
var string = "123 t16 456 t26 789 t8 321";
```

Marker is "t" and each is followed by two or one characters that represent its value, in this case 16, 26 and 8, so I need to remove t16, t26 and t8 (t8+blank space). I always remove two chars after the marker.

I understand how to do it with substring or slice - start a loop to get a position of each marker, remove both the marker and next two chars based on position of the marker, and continue with the loop until all markers and its values are removed.

Is there a better way - in terms of speed and it being a one line solution - to do it with regex?

Comment: Try this: `s.replace(/t.{2}/g, '')`

Comment: Write a regexp to match what you want to remove, then replace that with an empty string using `String#replace`.

Comment: @torazaburo It's pretty obvious from the question what the desired output should be, even before your edit fixing some minor grammar.

Comment: [`var marker = 't';
var regex = new RegExp('\\b' + marker + '.{1,2}\\s', 'g'); string.replace(regex, '')`](https://jsfiddle.net/w304h9sa/)

Comment: Do not add solutions to the question. Instead, accept the answer. If the solution was provided in a comment, ask the commenter to post it as an answer.

Comment: @torazaburo cleaner fish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string = string.replace(/t../g, '');
```

If you want it case-insensitive:

```
string = string.replace(/t../gi, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do :

```
s.replace(/t.{1,2}\s/g, '')
```

See it in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/egtv8D/1)